# Why is tinymce visual editor showing the background from my theme

Tags: visual-editor

In my theme I have the body background style set to a particular image (in style.css file). When editing the content under visual editor I have this same background I set in the theme. Is it possible to turn this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your theme register a custom stylesheet for the editor, this is possible via the function [add_editor_style()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_editor_style). Search for the function in your theme directory, maybe inside the `functions.php`.